# Count objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, count

I have an array like this:

```
[{"this":"that","int":5},{"this":"that","int":5}]
```

How can I count the number of objects({}) inside of an array with Javascript?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: with Array#length? or do you mean the object?

Comment: Were you really not able to look up the [Array.prototype.length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/length) property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try,

```
var cnt = 0;
var arr = [5 , 3 , "not an object" , {"this":"that","int":5},{"this":"that","int":5}];

arr.forEach(function(itm){
 if(!itm.__proto__.__proto__){
  cnt++;
 }
});

console.log(cnt + "normal objects are there"); //2
```

Comment: @krmax44 I glad that I understood your requirement. Try to accept it if you feel this answer has helped you. But this is not a compulsion. :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy Great solution, glad you understood what the OP was trying to say - no one else did. I have edited the original post (pending approval) to improve clarity to direct people to your answer.

Comment: @mhodges Both the sample and text in the question shows nothing of an array with mixed item types. Changing it will invalidate all answers but this, so I changed it back. If that where what the OP was after, a new question needs to be posted.

Comment: @LGSon Yeah, I don't think that the true intent was clearly communicated. Considering the fact that a simple .length did not work for the OP, I am guessing that the array is heterogeneous (or at least has the potential to be), which is why this solution is the only solution that worked.

Comment: @mhodges Still, one can't alter a posted question so it will invalidate the answers already given.

Answer (score 7):

```
[{"this":"that","int":5},{"this":"that","int":5}].length; // 2
```

Comment: @krmax44 You had a typo there. https://jsfiddle.net/52gp5wd2/1/ And i thought you just want to count how many objects are there other than primitives,arrays etc...

Comment: @JamesSnowy sorry, didn't typed it right in fiddle, but in the project, only the answer of RajaprabhuAravindasamy worked for me...

Answer (score 2):

```
var length = arrayName.length;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply like this:

```
var yourArrayName = arrayName.length
```

As when you have an `array` and use the `.length` it counts how many `objects` there are in the `array`.

Answer (score 0):

Object {} inside array [] treated as items so you find the length of array to count the item(s)

```
var $data=[{"this":"that","int":5},{"this":"that","int":5}];

    var count=$data.length
```

Comment: $data, just a variable name nothing else

Comment: i am using this convention while declaring the variable, you  can use your own convention

Comment: You have a right to use any convention to declare a variable, but if so bear in mind that, in the case of the $ sign, some libraries (e.g. jQuery) may use it too,  which could lead to confusion.